# Heap corruption detected, while deleting a dynamic 2d char array

Tags: c++, arrays, char, dynamic-arrays

I have written a class with char** class field(which is dynamic 2d array) named visa(basically i want there to be countries which a person has visited) and countriesVisited(in fact size of the array). I intentionally didn't use strings. I've added a class method, which adds countries to the mentioned array, but when i try to delete the array elements i get HEAP CORRUPTION detected: after Normal block (#158):

```
void ForeignPassport::addCountry(const char* country) {   
        char** tmp = new char* [countriesVisited + 1];

    for (int i = 0; i < countriesVisited+1; i++) {
        tmp[i] = new char[strlen(country)];
    }


    for (int i = 0; i < countriesVisited; i++) {
        int f = 0;
        while (visa[i][f-1] != '\0') {
            tmp[i][f] = visa[i][f];
            f++;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i <= strlen(country); i++) {
        if (i == strlen(country)) {
            tmp[countriesVisited][i] = '\0';
            break;
        }
        tmp[countriesVisited][i] = country[i];
    }
    countriesVisited++;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < countriesVisited-1; i++) {
        delete[]visa[i];
    }
    
    visa = tmp ;
    
}
```

Comment: When you allocate `tmp` you allocate space for N entries with the length of the new country you're adding. Unless every other country previously added is shorter than this you write past the bounds of that allocated memory when you copy the names across. You're also leaking whatever `visa` was pointing to since you delete all of the entries but not the actual variable.

Comment: Your code is far more elaborate than necessary. For example you're making an absolute meal of the null termination, and I suspect you are exceeding the array bounds when doing so. Just use `strdup()` for the strings, and `free()` them when done.

Comment: A `<=` in the exit condition of a for loop iterating over a container is almost always wrong. When you see one spend a little extra time making sure the loop doesn't go one loop too far.

Comment: Side note: `strlen(country)` isn't free. A smart compiler will see that `country` won't change and will call `strlen` once and save the result, but if your compiler's not smart, or you didn't ask it to be smart, the program will be searching through the string over and or again.

Comment: And why you think you have to use a loop to evaluate `strlen(country)` is a mystery. Not that you have to evaluate it at all, see above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tmp[i] = new char[strlen(country)];`

here you are allocating memory in amounts of strlen(country)
but in this loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= strlen(country); i++) {
        if (i == strlen(country)) {
            tmp[countriesVisited][i] = '\0';
            break;
        }
        tmp[countriesVisited][i] = country[i];
    }
```

here you are accessing to the memory which is not allocated and this not allowed,
so change the condition to `i < strlen(country)`